# Error during wrapup: Number of parameters to be estimated is larger than the number of observations

Tags: r, regression, metafor

I am running a meta-regression analysis in `metafor` package and my code is as follows

```
rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ duration_exp + feedstock_rename 
                    + temp_group + application_rate + fertilizer_app_rate + 
                      manure_app_rate + compost_app_rate + continent 
                    + feedstock_rename + annual_temp, method = "REML", data=.)
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
Error during wrapup: Number of parameters to be estimated is larger than the number of observations.
```

But when I remove "annual_temp" from the model it runs perfectly. I am not sure what is the problem. "annual_temp" is a continuous variable. Could you please suggest how I can solve this error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fit a model that has more parameters than you actually have observations. If it runs when you remove "annual_temp", then apparently that just pushes the number of parameters under the threshold, but the model is going to be useless as it will totally overfit. To solve this problem, you need to reduce the model complexity.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. As I understood there is nothing wrong with this model but in the model, I can't add too many moderators, is that correct?

Comment: Basically yes. If the number of moderators (or rather, parameters, since a single categorical moderator may be coded in terms of several dummy variables) becomes large relative to the number of studies you have, then you are running into issues with overfitting.